# Width issue of Rotated Image in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, rotation, zooming

I have written below code. Need to run on IE versions, so used filter for rotation. Clicking several times on the button, that will update the width of the image, will re-position the image.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Zoom Issue</title>

<style>
.ImgClass{
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
height : auto;
width : 100%;

}
.divClass{
width : 800px;
height : 750px;
}

</style>
</head>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function zoomImage(){
    document.getElementById('myImage').style.width = document.getElementById('myImage').offsetWidth  * 1.5;
}
</SCRIPT>

<body>
<input type="button" id='btnClick' value='Click' onClick="zoomImage();"/>
<DIV class='divClass'>
<IMG class='ImgClass' id='myImage' src='Image.jpg' />
</DIV>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Comment: IE 8, it is required to be run on IE 8.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me as if you are changing the wrong dimension. If you rotate it on its side width becomes height and height becomes width (unless you put your head on it's side):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Zoom Issue</title>
    <style>
    .ImgClass{
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
        height : 100%;
        width : auto;
    }
    .divClass{
        width : 800px;
        height : 750px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    function zoomImage(){   
        var img = document.getElementById('myImage');   
        img.style.height = e1.offsetHeight * 1.5 + "px";
    }
</SCRIPT>

<body>
    <input type="button" id='btnClick' value='Click' onClick="zoomImage();"/>
    <DIV class='divClass'>
        <img class='ImgClass' id='myImage' src="Images/IMG_6686.JPG">
    </DIV>
</body>
</html>
```

This seems to work fine for me in IE8.